# Post form values using JS without elements?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms, http-post

I have a model with properties, one of which is a collection.

I want to have a client JS function that sets that collection with some values (or send it to the controller-action via a separate param, or via model binder which I'm not really acquainted with).

How is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, for this you need to create your routes by javascript and create a function to capture the values ​​of url, or use the backbonejs, this already gives you this kind of thing (http://backbonejs.org/#Router)

Comment: Can you please post this as answer showing how? What about model binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send arbitrarily complex structures using JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: 123,
        items: [
            { foo: 'bar 1' },
            { foo: 'bar 2' },
            { foo: 'bar 3' }
        ]
    }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

and your controller action will take a view model that will match the JSON structure:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and here's the model definition matching this sample structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ItemViewModel[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not posting the values using JS, I'm submitting the form regularly, I just don't know how to set the collection property of the model in the posted form. Perhaps faking elements IS the best way (i.e. generating hidden elements with their `name` property set to `Model.CollectionProperty[0]`, `Model.CollectionProperty[1]` etc.), is that so?

Comment: If you are posting the form regularly then you should respect the standard naming convention for your input fields that the default model binder uses: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx If you are going to use hidden fields you could generate them like that: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CollectionProperty[index].SomeSubProperty)`.

Comment: Would be good if you include your comment in your answer, for reference.